# Unexpected identifier in javascript for videojs

Tags: javascript

I get the following error. What's wrong? 137 is the "for (let i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {" row.

I've uncommented "import videojs from 'video.js';" because I have that code right before this block. Please let me know if that's a problem. It works in some browsers so I'm not sure.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'i'. Expected either 'in' or 'of'
>   in enumeration syntax. (anonymous function) — plugins.js:137

```
/*! videojs-playlist-ui - v0.0.0 - 2015-3-12
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Brightcove
 * Licensed under the Apache-2.0 license. */

//import videojs from 'video.js';

// support VJS5 & VJS6 at the same time
const dom = videojs.dom || videojs;
const registerPlugin = videojs.registerPlugin || videojs.plugin;

// Array#indexOf analog for IE8
const indexOf = function(array, target) {
  for (let i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === target) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
};

// see https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/pointerevents.js
const supportsCssPointerEvents = (() => {
  let element = document.createElement('x');
  element.style.cssText = 'pointer-events:auto';
  return element.style.pointerEvents === 'auto';
})();

const defaults = {
  className: 'vjs-playlist',
  playOnSelect: false,
  supportsCssPointerEvents
};
[...]
```

Comment: Your browser is probably doesn't support `let` so it thinks that `let` is a variable name as in: `for(let in obj)`.

Comment: const and let with IE8?

Comment: Aha, any workaround? Something that does the same thing, but different?

Comment: Use the old lovely `var` instead of `let`.

Comment: @ibrhimmahrir - Is there a browser that supports `for..of` but *not* `let`? Seems odd that the error message seems to say that `of` would be OK as in `for(let of obj)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn ... or `const` but not `let` (which is even oddier). I was just wondering the same. I even copied that `let` he used and compared it to `"let"` to check if there is any odd unicode character disguising itself as `l`, `e` or `t`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir var seems to do it but I also get this error on line 146: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'". Which is the line with "const supportsCssPointerEvents = (() => {". Ideas?

Comment: On which browser this is running?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir An old iPad with iOS 9.3.5 hehe, but I've heard from people running other browsers where (probably) this script messes it up. I'm having problem with all my jQuery breaks. It all works in old browsers when I remove this script, but I like what the script does in the browsers where it works so I hope I can fix it https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist-ui

Comment: Replace all instances of `const` and `let` with `var` and all arrow functions with normal ones.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Cool! I've replaced all let and const and it still works. Now the Unexpected token is still there. How would you re-write this, and I can hopefully figure out the rest myself. `var supportsCssPointerEvents = (() => {
  var element = document.createElement('x');
  element.style.cssText = 'pointer-events:auto';
  return element.style.pointerEvents === 'auto';
})();`

Comment: That's an arrow function. `() => { ... }` should be `function() { ... }` and `(a, b) => { .... }` should be `function (a, b] { ... }` and `(a, b) => something` should be `function (a, b) { return something; }`.

Comment: Here you can use a transpiler like `babel` to convert ECMAScript 6 syntax to ECMAScript 5 syntax. https://babeljs.io/repl/. I don't recommend using transpilers online unless you make sure they're safe to use (the link I gave you is safe). Paste your entire code in the left textarea and replace it with the result on the right textarea.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Beautiful! I ran it through Babel and now everything seems to be working! Great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove *let* keyword in all the for loop. I observed JavascriptCore engine in Safari doesn't permit to use temp variables for intialization.